# Configuring N64 controller in RetroPie

Tags: configuration, controller, raspberry-pi

I have been trying to set up the RetroPie project on my raspberry pi over the last few weeks. I finally got it to the point where I could successfully run roms, and navigate the project. I am having trouble with one last aspect of the project: the controller configuration. I have a RetroLink Nintendo 64 USB controller, and I require assistance with configuring the controller. After configuring controller for single player nintendo 64 rom use, I also would like to configure more controllers for multiplayer gameplay (they would be the same controller, I will just buy more). Please remember that I have absolutely no linux experience. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2):

**RetroPie 2.2**

**Part One**

First thing you'll need to do after you boot into emulation station is press "f4" to get into your command line.

Then type these commands in order pressing "enter" between each command.

```
sudo chown pi /opt/retropie/configs/all/retroarch.cfg

cd /opt/retropie/emulators/RetroArch/installdir/bin

sudo ./retroarch-joyconfig -j 1 >> /opt/retropie/configs/all/retroarch.cfg
```

Follow the instructions in the command line and it should get your controller up and running in emulation station and in your games.

**Part 2** (not sure if this works yet I'm in the middle of testing it)

From the command line type `startx` and boot into the gui.

Open up the file explorer and go to the directory  `/opt/retropie/configs/all/` and open `retroarch.cfg` in your file editor.

Scroll all the way to the bottom and you'll find a a section like this:

```
input_player1_joypad_index = "0"
input_player1_b_btn = "1"
input_player1_y_btn = "3"
input_player1_select_btn = "6"
input_player1_start_btn = "7"
input_player1_up_axis = "-1"
input_player1_down_axis = "+1"
input_player1_left_axis = "-0"
input_player1_right_axis = "+0"
input_player1_a_btn = "0"
input_player1_x_btn = "2"
input_player1_l_btn = "4"
input_player1_r_btn = "5"
input_player1_l2_btn = "6"
input_player1_r2_btn = "6"
input_player1_l3_btn = "6"
input_player1_r3_btn = "6"
input_player1_l_x_plus_btn = "6"
input_player1_l_x_minus_btn = "6"
input_player1_l_y_plus_btn = "6"
input_player1_l_y_minus_btn = "6"
input_player1_r_x_plus_btn = "6"
input_player1_r_x_minus_btn = "6"
input_player1_r_y_plus_btn = "6"
input_player1_r_y_minus_btn = "6"
input_player1_joypad_index = "0"
input_player1_b_btn = "1"
input_player1_y_btn = "3"
input_player1_select_btn = "6"
input_player1_start_btn = "7"
input_player1_up_axis = "-1"
input_player1_down_axis = "+1"
input_player1_left_axis = "-0"
input_player1_right_axis = "+0"
input_player1_a_btn = "0"
input_player1_x_btn = "2"
input_player1_l_btn = "4"
input_player1_r_btn = "5"
input_player1_l2_btn = "4"
input_player1_r2_btn = "5"
input_player1_l3_btn = "4"
input_player1_r3_btn = "5"
input_player1_l_x_plus_axis = "-0"
input_player1_l_x_minus_axis = "+0"
input_player1_l_y_plus_axis = "+1"
input_player1_l_y_minus_axis = "-1"
input_player1_r_x_plus_axis = "+0"
input_player1_r_x_minus_axis = "-0"
input_player1_r_y_plus_axis = "+1"
input_player1_r_y_minus_axis = "-1"
```

That's the section laying out the configuration for player 1, copy all that text and change all `player1` to `player2` and I think you have to increment the top most line...

`input_player1_joypad_index = "0" -> input_player1_joypad_index = "1"`

that's where i haven't tested yet.

Anyway I hope it all works.

EDIT: I just tried out my usb controllers in a co-op setting with two players and this solution worked for me.

Comment: Just so you're aware: RetroPi changes their file structure very often so this answer may not be applicable to the version of RetroPie that you're using. I would personally recommend going else where for your retro-gaming wants/needs. I personally will be using ignition.io which uses the same "back-end" as RetroPi, namly, RetroArch. It does, however, have a node based GUI.